# Encountering warning message "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let me come straight to the point the point. I was working on a React project for code like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'

export default function MyOrder () {
  const [orderData, setorderData] = useState({})
  const fetchMyOrder = async () => {
    await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/myOrder', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: localStorage.getItem('userEmail')
      })
    }).then(async (res) => {
      const response = await res.json()
      setorderData(response)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMyOrder()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Navbar />
      </div>

      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {orderData !== {}
            ? Array(orderData).map((data) => {
              return data.orderData
                ? data.orderData.order_data
                  .slice(0)
                  .reverse()
                  .map((item) => {
                    return item.map((arrayData) => {
                      return (
                            <div key={arrayData.order_date}>
                              {arrayData.order_date
                                ? (
                                <div className="m-auto mt-5">
                                  {(data = arrayData.order_date)}
                                  <hr />
                                </div>
                                  )
                                : (
                                <div className="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                                  <div
                                    className="card mt-3"
                                    style={{
                                      width: '16rem',
                                      maxHeight: '360px'
                                    }}
                                  >
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                      <h5 className="card-title">
                                        {' '}
                                        {arrayData.name}{' '}
                                      </h5>{' '}
                                      <div
                                        className="container w-100 p-0"
                                        style={{
                                          height: '38px'
                                        }}
                                      >
                                        <span className="m-1">
                                          {' '}
                                          {arrayData.qty}{' '}
                                        </span>{' '}
                                        <span className="m-1">
                                          {' '}
                                          {arrayData.size}{' '}
                                        </span>{' '}
                                        <span className="m-1"> {data} </span>{' '}
                                        <div className=" d-inline ms-2 h-100 w-20 fs-5">
                                          {' '}
                                          ₹{arrayData.price}
                                          /-{' '}
                                        </div>{' '}
                                      </div>{' '}
                                    </div>{' '}
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                  )}
                            </div>
                      )
                    })
                  })
                : ''
            })
            : ''}{' '}
        </div>
      </div>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I was able to render the results from the database reliably. Only the issue was that I was seeing this error:
`react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`. I don't know why it is saying that I am using a list which I am not. I would like to know why it is happening so.

[image: This was my result for the above code]

Here is the sample database snippet

```json
{"orderData":{"_id":"63024fd2be92d0469bd9e31a","email":"mohanDas@gmail.com","order_data":[[[{"id":"62ff20fbaed6a15f800125e9","name":"Chicken Fried Rice","qty":"4","size":"half","price":520},{"id":"62ff20fbaed6a15f800125ea","name":"Veg Fried Rice","qty":"4","size":"half","price":440}],"2022-08-21T15:31:30.239Z"],[[{"id":"62ff20fbaed6a15f800125f4","name":"Mix Veg Pizza","qty":"4","size":"medium","price":800},{"id":"62ff20fbaed6a15f800125f3","name":"Chicken Double Cheese Pizza","qty":"4","size":"regular","price":480}],"2022-08-21T15:32:38.861Z"]],"__v":0}}
```

Comment: There no need to use `await` with `setorderData`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I my simplified version I have not implement the await.

Answer (score 0):

"orderData" is nested within an object, and it contains an array.

**PS:** I do not have your API, so I have manually hard coded your object into a single state and am iterating through it.

You can made these changes to make it work:

**Here is the codesandbox link:** https://codesandbox.io/s/react-counter-functional-component-forked-xq8xfj?file=/src/Counter.js

=> **Modified Logic**

```
 <div className="container">
        {Array.isArray(orderData) &&
          orderData[0].orderData.order_data.map((order, index) => {
            const orderItems = order[0];
            const orderDate = order[1];

            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <div className="m-auto mt-5">
                  {orderDate}
                  <hr />
                </div>

                {orderItems.map((item, itemIndex) => {
                  return (
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3" key={itemIndex}>
                      <div className="card mt-3">
                        <img
                          src={item.img}
                          className="card-img-top"
                          alt="..."
                          style={{ height: "120px", objectFit: "fill" }}
                        />

                        <div className="card-body">
                          <h5 className="card-title">{item.name}</h5>

                          <div
                            className="container w-100 p-0"
                            style={{ height: "38px" }}
                          >
                            <span className="m-1">{item.qty}</span>
                            <span className="m-1">{item.size}</span>
                            <span className="m-1">{orderDate}</span>
                            <div className="d-inline ms-2 h-100 w-20 fs-5">
                              ₹{item.price}/-
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
```

Comment: This is my api code:
```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Order = require('../models/Orders')

router.post('/myOrder', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const eID = await Order.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    res.json({ orderData: eID })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message)
    res.status(500).send('Internal server error!')
  }
})

module.exports = router
```
I am seeing that my console is showing me "cannot read the properties of undefined"

Comment: Hey, I am not sure what you're talking about. Are you getting 'undefined' error on backend side ?

Comment: I think "Yes" on my response it is returning { "orderData": null }

Comment: Hey, You need to debug the issue and fixed the same on backend side.  I have posted a solution for your iteration problem on the client side with live demo. You can check that. For the backend, You need to post a new question with demo, So people can help you out.

Comment: Hey, So I have fixed the issue with the backend. Now I am seeing this error with key prop  as I have uploaded in the screenshot. Can you tell me why it is throwing this error. Even if I try to use a index parameter in the map to be used as key. It is no longer rendering the contents of the page.